# Change in running behavior of sklearn code between laptop and desktop

Tags: python, scipy, fortran, scikit-learn

I am trying to debug a Fortran warning in some Sklearn code that runs perfectly on my laptop...but after transferring to my desktop (which is a fresh Ubuntu 15.10, fresh Pycharm, and fresh Anaconda3), I get the following error when running `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score`:

> /anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib
>   /hashing.py:197: DeprecationWarning: Changing the shape of non-C contiguous 
>   array by
>   descriptor assignment is deprecated. To maintain
>   the Fortran contiguity of a multidimensional Fortran
>   array, use 'a.T.view(...).T' instead
>    obj_bytes_view = obj.view(self.np.uint8)

The command I am submitting to `cross_val_score` is:

```
test_results = cross_val_score(learner(**learner_args),data,y=classes,n_jobs=n_jobs,scoring='accuracy',cv=LeaveOneOut(data.shape[0]))
```

Where the iterator is the sklearn cross validation object...and nothing else special is going on.   What could be happening here?  Am I missing some installation step?

Comment: Is it possible this has always been an issue and is only being reported now because you're running newer code that throws the deprecated warning?

Comment: You might be right.  Either way, I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Maybe it is something within scikit that is now deprecated?

Comment: @bordeo any update on this? I am facing same issue. updating joblib to latest does not help either.

Comment: @SrikarAppal I actually just did `import warnings` and then `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`, because my deadline is tonight...but I'll make sure to post anything I run into...

Comment: @bordeo after the warnings scikit just "hangs". You saying ignoring the warnings solved your problem?

Comment: @SrikarAppal  yeah, ignoring it solved it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record for people like me who found this SO post via Google, this is has been recorded as issue [#6370](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6370) for scikit-learn.

As mentioned there:

> This problem has been fixed in joblib master. It won't be fixed in scikit-learn until:
>
> 1) we do a new joblib release
>
> 2) we update scikit-learn master to have the new joblib release
>
> 3) if you are using released versions of scikit-learn, which I am guessing you are, you will have to wait until there is a new scikit-learn release

I was able to use the above workaround from @bordeo :

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```